# Series and Finitness -- Quotient of close terms bounded by close terms of finite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, summation

Let $\sum u_n$ and $\sum v_n$ two series. Assume for all n $u_n,v_n>0$ and $\sum v_n$ is finite and 
$$
\frac{u_{n+2}}{u_n} \le \frac{v_{n+2}}{v_n}\qquad \text{ for all n }\in \mathbb{N}
$$
Show that $\sum u_n$ is finite.

---

Define $w_n = u_{2n}$ and $a_n=v_{2n}$
Since $v_n>0$ we know that $\sum a_n$ is finite.

Applying the logarithm and summing, we have $$\sum_{n=0}^{p-1}(\ln(w_{n+1})-\ln(w_n))\le \sum_{n=0}^{p-1}(\ln(a_{n+1})-\ln(a_n)) = \ln(a_p)-\ln(a_0)$$

Hence
$$w_p \le k\,a_p \qquad \text{ for all p }\in \mathbb{N}$$ where $k=\exp(\ln(w_0)-\ln(a_0))$.
Hence $\sum w_n$ is finite.

I can do the same with $u_{2n+1}$ and so by sum of finite series $\sum u_n$ is finite.

Do you have any remark and/or other solutions ?

Comment: Seems fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

An other answer:
write 
$$\frac{w_{n+1}}{w_n}\le \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$$

Fix M>0. The sequence $(\frac{w_n}{a_n})_n$ is descreasing so there is a integer N such that $\frac{w_n}{a_n}< M$ for all $n>N$.

Then for all $n>N$, $w_{n+1}\le \frac{w_{n}}{a_{n}}a_{n+1}\le M a_{n+1}$

So $\sum w_n$ is finite.
Like $\sum u_{2n+1}$ is finite, hence $\sum u_n$ is finite.

Comment: this is wrong since $N$ may not exist ....